# How to add independent UIs to a .NET project?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

I have multiple UIs each communicate to a device. For that I first created a Class Library and then added a UI and then built the project without any errors.

Now I would like to incorporate all these UIs into a project. This way I can create different applications. I created a Windows Form project and added each class as a DLL file.

However, ***the problem is that I cannot access the Form in each class and add them to the Form in the new project***.

How should I import the UIs into my final Windows Form project?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project in the solution.  Move all those forms into the new project.  Reference that project from your main project.  When you build, that new project will be its own .DLL that you can use in other solutions and you can reference it and use those forms.